# Unmanaged VF page throws an error: Method not visible: [UnmanagedCtrl].getSample()

Tags: apex, visualforce, visibility

Problem - We have unmanaged apex page and unmanaged apex controller. Apex page includes managed package VF component in it.
Apex class looks like this:

```
public class UnmanagedCtrl{
   public String getSample(){
      // code..
      return value;
   }
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller='UnmanagedCtrl'>
   <myNameSpace:ManagedComponent param1='{!sample}'/>
</apex:page>
```

This VF page sometimes throws an error: **Method not visible: [UnmanagedCtrl].getSample()**

We did back and forth with salesforce support but no luck. They are still investigating this issue on their end. We also did check if the managed code is causing any issue, but since both the page and class are unmanaged, it didn't help.

Also tried few options such as:

1. When we update the VF page version, the issue goes away temporarily and comes back again randomly.
2. When we update the apex class or VF page, the issue goes away temporarily and comes back again randomly.
3. Tried to make apex class 'without sharing', it didn't solve the issue. - This was Salesforce recommendation.
4. Tried to change the class & method visibility to global, it didn't solve the issue.

***What we noticed is, even if we fake update (just edit and save without any code change) the page or class it solves the issue temporarily for a day and user start facing this issue again which is frustrating.***

What could be the root cause of this issue? Has anyone ever faced similar issue. If yes, what was the solution? Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Doing the dummy edit/save makes me think that this may be an issue with the bytecode cache on Salesforce's end, but Salesforce themselves would be the only ones able to say if that's the case. Is this happening for multiple users (or rather, multiple profiles) or just a single user? Do you have any other people/teams/processes that do deployments? If so, might their deployments be overwriting your controller (or profiles/permission sets)? Does the "random" timing line up with other deployments that happen? Do you have a rough example of the timeframe for the "random" timing (hours/weeks/etc)?

Comment: This is happening for all the users. There is only one team who does the deployment and we made sure that they are not overwriting the controller or any other component. The timeframe varies from 1 day to 1 week, it's not fixed.

Comment: Have you tried enabling setup audit tracking to see if there is some update of the controller? I know you said the team are not updating it, but I am wondering if some CI automation or similar might be doing something.

Comment: Boy, if I had this problem I would create a clone of the VF page/controller (different name), and then try again as the bytecode cache explanation matches an experience I had a few years ago.

Comment: @PhilW We did check that, but did not find anything concrete.

Comment: @cropredy I tried this in the past, but then we started facing the same error for the new VF page. Also tried creating new apex class, but ran into same error.

Comment: Is this on a trialforce org, with the package being on the source org?

Comment: @PhilW No. This is happening in customer production org.

Comment: Was that generated from a trialforce template?

Comment: @PhilW We don't use trialforce templates. We create the org from partner portal environment hub and convert that into production & then deploy our solution onto it. Also SF asked us to set the latest version on the VF page and controllers to resolve this, but that also did not work.